# RSS to a github file?

Tags: github, rss

Is there a way to get changes feed to this file:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commits/master/CHANGELOG.md

My goal is to simply know when angularjs, or any other repo I consume, has come up with a release.

Is this the way?
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way wich works for any repo: use the releases atom feed.
The general form is 
`https://github.com/<owner>/<repo>/releases.atom`

And the one you're looking for is available at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/releases.atom

Comment: So close man, but what about the release notes? Or at least if it would link to them.

Comment: Ha, I don't think you can get them directly... But, you also have the feed of all commits, so you could combine both to identify the list of commits between 2 releases :)

Answer (score 5):

You can get an Atom feed for individual files or folders by adding @.atom@ to the URL of the history page. In your case, this:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commits/master/CHANGELOG.md.atom